# Us an existing random function to generate another random function

Tags: algorithm, random, generator

Suppose I have a function `int fun1();` it can return a random number x1 satisfies `0<x1<m`.

How can I make use of the function `fun1()` to generate another function `int fun2()`,so that it can return a random number x2 satisfies`0<x2<n`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to write something like:

```
return fun1() * n / m;
```